# require a phtml file, but I can't call the javascript function in this file

Tags: javascript, php

I require a phtml file in my module's Module.php

```
require __DIR__.'/view/advice/advice/advicemodal.phtml';
```

and the advicemodal.phtml contains a button and two modals, and their css style and javascript onclick function, the file code is

```
<head><style>...</style></head>
<div>
  <a herf="#" onclick="add()" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">add</a>
</div>
<div>...two modals...</div>
<script>
function add(){}
function submit(){}
</script>
```

At first I thought the function written is wrong, but I found it doesn't call the function,so I don't know how to handle it. So please tell me what it is the problem, thank you!

Comment: Any errors present in your console?

Comment: @Darren, the button is showed, and can toggle a modal, but I cant call my onclick functions, cause it said the add and submit are not defined

Comment: Try putting your `<script> function add() {...//etc` at the top of your file before you call the `onclick`.

Comment: @Darren, Thank u so much for your suggestion, I found my problem in my console.

Comment: Glad it sort of helped haha!